# sublime text 2 snippet error - Empty Key?

Tags: sublimetext2, code-snippets

[image: Sublime Text 2 snippet parsing error]

Here is the error:

```
Error parsing content for snippet Packages/User/servlet-definition.sublime-snippet: Empty key
```

and here is the code:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>$1</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>${2:spray.servlet.Servlet30ConnectorServlet}</servlet-class>
        <async-supported>${3:true}</async-supported>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>$1</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>$(4:/*}</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    ${5}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>sdef</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>XML</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem isn't that Sublime Text 2 [thinks you're using a regular expression](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html?highlight=snippets#substitutions), it's that `$(4:/*}` should be enclosed by *just brackets*, not a parenthesis and a bracket. As it is now, Sublime Text is wondering why your `$` isn't part of a variable. Use `${4:/*}` instead, and you should be fine.

Also, you can use `$0` to define [the exit position for the cursor](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html?highlight=snippets#fields)—it looks like you're using `$5` for that purpose, which will be a problem in the future if you want to add more fields.

Answer (score 0):

$(4:/*} is the problem. Not sure why, seems like maybe it is being evaluated as a regex. I tried escaping the forward slash but no luck. I just removed the default text.